# Can I move mongodb atlas data to aws ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb-atlas

I'm beginner of programming.
I created App about 3 months ago with MongoDB.
I use mongo db atlas M10 Tier.
But, I want to setup mongo db in new aws ec2 server and want to move data from atlas to here.
Is there no idea to this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/

Answer (score 0):

If I have a mongodb in Atlas which have three db called `db1`、`db2`、`db3`

I execute below command at D:\

```
mongodump -h <connecting string to your mongodb Atlas>
```

D:\dump\db1

D:\dump\db2

D:\dump\db3

```
mongorestore -h <connecting string to your EC2 mongodb> -d dbAtlas D:\dump\db1
```

EC2 mongodb would now have `dbAtlas` which is a copy of `db1`